# Accessing an element without initializing the vector. Do I need extra space?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, data-structures, computer-science

I am reading about a "trick" (references to Aho,Hopcroft,Ullman) on how to use a data vector without explicitely initializing it.

The trick is to use 2 extra vectors (`From` `To`) and an integer `Top`.

Before accesing an element in the vector `DATA[i]` if a specific condition between `From` `To` and `Top` is met the element `i` has been considered as initialized.

If the condition does not meet then the element is initialized and the `From` `To` and `Top` are updated as follows:

`Top = Top + 1`
`From[i] = Top`
`To[Top] = i`
`Data[i] = 0`

The condition is to know whether an element has been initialized is:
 `From[i] <= Top && To[From[i]] == i`
If true then it has been initialized.

My question is: why are the extra vectors needed?

From my point of view, if I access an element and `i<=Top` then the element is initialized.  Then I increment `i` i.e. `i++`.

In this case if `i <= TOP` means that `DATA[i]` has been initialized.

Am I not seeing a boundary case? It seems to me this is enough.
Or am I wrong?

Comment: Can you give a specific reference for this?  You haven't described how `From`, `To` and `Top` are updated.

Comment: Have updated with the update of `From`, `To` and `Top`.I read this from a part of `Programming Pearls` that mentions it is from `Aho etc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time-saving idea is that none of `To, From, Data` need to be initialized beforehand, and all of them can be arrays so large that initialization takes appreciable time.

At the outset, any entry of any of the arrays can have any value.  It could be the case, by chance, that for some `i`, `To[From[i]] == i`.  (That condition can be true by chance *or* when `Data[From[i]]` has been set.)  However, `Top` is counting the number of `Data` elements set so far, so that the test `From[i] <= Top` can distinguish cases completely.

Answer (score 3):

If this is the example I am thinking of, then you don't know the order in which the elements of DATA[] will be accessed - it is used as a sparse array, for example the values in an almost empty hash table. So the first 3 items to be accessed might be DATA[113], DATA[29], and DATA[123123], not DATA[0], DATA[1], and DATA[2]. You could in fact get away without From[], in which case To would store {113, 29, 123123} - but then you would have to search all of To every time you wanted to see if an element of DATA was valid, e.g. if you wanted to see if 123123 was valid you would see To[0] = 113 no luck To[1] = 29 no luck To[2] = 123123 Oh yes 123123 is valid.